# MYOB API. Using getrange against server returns localhost in URI

Tags: myob

When I use getrange against a server the URIs all show localhost.
Is this normal?
I get a communication error when I go forward and want to eliminate this rather basic item.
Thanks in advance
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public address on the server needs to get set to the correct network address. The default seems to be localhost, so any links generated by the server will only work when opened on the server itself.

You can change the public network address in the MYOB API config file. That should be located on the server at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MYOB\API\2.x.x.x\`. The xml config file should be called `MYOB.AccountRight.API.WindowsServiceHost.exe.config`.

In the config file, under `<appSettings>` there should be a `PublicAddressServer` key. Update the corresponding value with the correct network address or DNS name for the server.

Lastly, restart the MYOB API service for the changes to take effect. The Windows service name should be `MYOB AccountRight API Service`.

Give that a try and see if it helps!

Edit: Source - http://myobapi.tumblr.com/post/70231017169/how-to-change-config-variables-for-the-desktop-api

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks